# compare 2 values to 1 value in c#

Tags: c#, if-statement

Any easier way to write this if statement

```
if (value1 <= 0 || value2 <= 0)
```

For example some think like `if ((value1 || value2) <= 0`

Comment: Just.. why? `value1 <= 0 || value2 <= 0` seems pretty clear.

Comment: How much easier do you want it? even your "improvement" is 3 comparisons (at most)

Comment: is just if i have 10 differents values and its the same number i want to compare it to and i change the value i need to do it 10 times

Comment: A quick look at the ridiculous solutions in the answers to the duplicate question should reassure you that the way you have is the best way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, your way is correct. If you have more than two values and you want to know if any of them is less  than or equal to zero use an array

```
if(new [] { value1, value2, value3, ... }.Any(x => x <= 0))
```

Comment: thanks that was the way i was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

in this case :

```
if (value1 <= 0 || value2 <= 0)
```

if `value1 <=0` is `true`  then it will short circut the evaluation and directly go inside the if loop as

```
1 || 0 = 1
1 || 1 = 1
```